# How to interpret the math behind detecting a shake event in Android?

Tags: java, android, sensors, motion, shake

I see a lot of answers online and they all have similar copy pasted code but none really have an explanation of the math that they use. I have a URL to the code on tutorialspoint which is the same as the answers I see on stackoverflow. However can someone explain to me this portion of the code:

```
   private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     float x = event.values[0];
     float y = event.values[1];
     float z = event.values[2];
     mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
     mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
     float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
     // What is this doing?
     mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
     if (mAccel > 12) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shake event detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }
```

What is this line supposed to be doing

```
mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
```

Where did the 0.9f come from and why are we multiplying it by itself and adding the delta? My physics isn't strong so it's not obvious to me.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-detect-shake-event-in-android-app

Comment: This is probably damping, the `0.9` is called the damping ratio/coefficient. It's used to stabilize the output, so that the values don't change all of a sudden. Also the `mAccelCurrent` is calculated with Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: But their math looks wrong, it should be something like `mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + mAccelCurrent * 0.1f` if this is really damping. They also don't seem to [take gravity into account](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion).

Comment: @Nicolas Is 0.9 arbitrary here?

Comment: Yes and no, usually damping ratios are between 0.85 and <1, higher values results in more damping. The result also depends on the update time, so there should be something to only allow updates every 100 ms or so.

Comment: why the 0.1f? @Nicolas

Comment: It's `1 - ratio` so `1 - 0.9`. Think of damping as a weighted average. You multiply each value by its weight then divide by the sum of weights.

Comment: Ah is that right, thank you so much for explaining this concept haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the code, also on the tutorialspoint page you linked. I see 3 steps in the algorithm:

1. `mAccelCurrent` is calculated as the current absolute value of the acceleration
2. `delta` is calculated as the difference between the current and previous absolute value of acceleration. This is done to get rid of constant acceleration value (gravity) and amplfy the shaking movement (change of acceleration).
3. `mAccel` is calculated as the [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) of `delta`, a first order filtering, with a 0.9 coefficient, that, depending on the timing that this function is called, can be a high value or low value (if it's called frequently, it's a low value). You are right saying that a `0.1f` multiplication looks to be missing, but if you look at the code in the protected `void onCreate` function, you can see that `mAccel` is initialized at `10f`. In other words, `mAccel` is 10 times the exponential smoothing of `delta`.
4. The result is then compared to 12, which looks to me as an arbitrary value.

You could use the 0.1 multiplication if you preferred, it would be enough to reduce by 10 times also the value to which it's compared (1.2 instead of 12)